# z.run("paragraphId") not working in Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to run paragraphs using zeppelin spark object method

```
z.run("noteId","paragraphId")
z.run("paragraphId")
```

I have tried both the methods, but nothing seems to be triggering the next paragraph. I do not get any errors also. Please let me know if I am missing something here.

On checking the zeppelin server logs I am getting the below error :

```
ERROR [2020-08-26 15:46:37,742] ({Thread-35} RemoteInterpreterEventPoller.java[run]:250) - Can't handle event RemoteInterpreterEvent(type:RUN_INTERPRETER_CONTEXT_RUNNER, data:{"logger":{"traceCapable":true,"name":"org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$ParagraphRunner"},"noteId":"2FHDFMR16","paragraphId":"20200819-131115_701985359"})
org.apache.zeppelin.rest.exception.ForbiddenException: HTTP 403 Forbidden
        at org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer.onRemoteRunParagraph(NotebookServer.java:2153)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterEventPoller.run(RemoteInterpreterEventPoller.java:141)
```

I have created my notebook using the admin user only. Do we need to provide any special access? I am just using admin user.

**Update 1:**

I changed notebook settings in which we removed user and owner permissions. It's triggering, but it's with an anonymous user. It will be a problem if we are working in multi-user environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of that

Try

```
z.z.run
```